# Search Q or A's I've upvoted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, upvotes

I rarely mark questions as favorites and I lost my 'search history' in my browser, so finding gems is a bit trickier than one would like.

My question is **how can I search for posts I've upvoted?**

*Under Activity I can't find any search box, how do you search your votes or actions?*

Comment: I think this is a good question, but still I wonder why only the question one upvoted themselves would count as gems? Basically all the highly upvoted question in the preferred tags should be potential gems and that is possible. You can filter the search by tags and then sort by score.

Comment: After you upvote for 10 yrs (> 6000 votes) and you work solely within a single tag, sometimes you want to search things you know worked in the past, but they are now stashed in 20,000,000 questions.

Comment: I understand the rationale and unfortunately it looks as if the software running SO does not offer that functionality, short of scraping the votes pages in your profile and then using your own search on them, you can only wait for the company to implement it (my advice: don't wait, you could become very old waiting). I would wish for that functionality too, but the second best is just googling the problem and hoping Google is smart enough to send you back to something that worked for you in the past.

Comment: It seems you can search in your favorites `infavorites:mine`, so maybe write yourself a script that automatically parses the upvotes page(s) of your profile and marks all questions that you upvoted as favorite and let it run regularly. Or a user script that does it online (whenever you upvote something, mark it as favorite).

Comment: @Trilarion that is very handy, guess I will be using the Favourites more often now. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

In your [activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/495455/jeremy-thompson?tab=topactivity) tab you have an option called *Votes*.

It wouldn't be visible for anyone except yourself. I posted mine below. Click on *Votes* and select *Upvote* to view all the upvoted posts by you.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't give you an option search